# cloning into remote repositories in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository

**Steps i did :-**

1.Installed `mercurial in both server (virtually both are win-7) and client`.
2.Created a repository with hg init, then added one file and commit ....
3. Then hg serve in server.
4.In client if i make hg clone **http://{192.168.3.6:port}/repo**

***Note:- that '{' is not there in real case i given. Post is not allowing ip's so i did*** that

5.Error in server is

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('', 49750)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 582, in process_request_thread
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 323, in finish_request
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 48, in __init__
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 638, in __init__
  File "BaseHTTPServer.pyc", line 342, in handle
  File "BaseHTTPServer.pyc", line 310, in handle_one_request
  File "socket.pyc", line 476, in readline
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote ho
st
```

What should i do to rectify this ?
Requirement is i want to clone into remote repo through http.
I want to set for 3 member team working in LAN.All are windows 7 machines.

I am new to Mercurial .. please tell me where i am going wrong ?

**UPDATE :**

```
Silly mistake i missed a space between source and destination in the hg clone http:/- - - / {space} repo
```

**It got Working.Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry..

Silly mistake i missed a space between source and destination in the hg clone http:/- - - / {space} repo.
I referred this [link](http://hginit.com/02.html).It is mentioned like

**C:\Users\rose> hg clone http://joel.example.com:8000/ recipes**

I failed to look that space in between that / and recipies.